# Xposed module for home key configuration while phone is locked

Tags: settings, buttons, home-button, xposed-framework

Is there an Xposed module for configuring the home key behavior (and maybe other hw keys) while the phone is locked or in sleep state, and will it also affect the home button default unlocked behaviors? e.g. torch on long press home key while locked/sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and it's called [Xposed Additions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) - available as a free or paid version on the play store. I use it to disable the power button wake on my Galaxy S4 and replace it with the "media play/pause" function and it works flawlessly.

Comment: App launching and tasker integration are listed as pending features for quite a while in Xposed Additions pro, is there another module that can do this?